# For $p$-Sylow Subgroup find normal subgroup $N$ such that $G=NP$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

> If $G$ is a finite group and its $p$-Sylow subgroup $P$ lies in the center of $G$, prove that there exists a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ with $P \cap N =\{ e\}$ and $PN = G$.

The other answers mention Burnside Transfer theorem but it's not in my course so is there any other way?

I started in following way: Let $|G|=p^am$ where a is the highest power of $p$. Since $P$ lies in the center $P$ is normal hence $G/P$ is a group $\{ P,g_1P,....,g_{m-1}P\}$.  I don't think this leads anywhere. Any help how to proceed?

Another try: By induction suppose it's true or subgroups of order $p^{a-1}m$ then there is a element $x$ of order $p$ in $Z(G)$. Now consider the group $G/\langle x\rangle$ which has order $p^{a-1}m$. It has $p$-sylow subgroup and $\overline{N}$ with order $p^a-1$ and $m$ respectively. Hence their corresponding subgroups in $G$ are $P$ and $N$ with order $p^a$ and $mp$ respectively and both are normal. Now we can write $N$ as $\langle p\rangle M$ for some subgroup $M$.

But I feel like there are there are lot of missing pieces if anyone can help fill them.

Comment: I think strong induction on a could work, if you can handle the case $a=1$ but this case does not seem that easy to me. If you know about the link between central extensions and cohomology, solving your problem can be done this way: take $P$ a central Sylow subgroup. Then$ G/P$ is a group with order coprime to |P|. The exact sequence $1→P→G→G/P→1$ corresponds to an element of  $H^2(G/P,P)$. But this cohomology is killed by the order of $G/P$ and by the order of $P$, so it is zero. In particular, your sequence splits, meaning that $G\simeq P\times G/P$, and we are done.

Comment: To expand my comment on induction, (no need strong induction, in fact) assuming you can handle the case $a=1$: keeping your notation, pick a $p$-Sylow $P/\langle x\rangle$ of $G/\langle x\rangle$ and convince yourself that it is central in the quotient. Then pick a normal subgroup $N/\langle x\rangle$ satisfying the dersired properties.  Since $N$ has order $pm$, $\langle x\rangle$ is  central $p$-Sylow of $N$ so  you can write $N=\langle x\rangle N'$. Now you should convince yourself that $N'$ does the job, keeping in mind that $P\cap N=\langle x\rangle$.

Comment: Remembert that $\vert P\vert =p^a$ and $\vert N'\vert=m$ + the fact that $P$ and $N'$ are normal are enough to get $P\cap N'$ trivial and $G=PN'$ (why ?).

Comment: This does not solve the main difficulty, though: how to prove in an elementary way the case $a=1$ ?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I don't have knowledge of cohomology so i didn't get your 1st suggestion. I can't even find solution of this anywhere, it's actually a double star marked problem in I.N. Herstein which tends to be this difficult.

Comment: The problem reduces easily to the case $|P|=p$. But I am not aware of any solution that does not involve using either the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem or Burnside's Transfer Theorem. BTT is really not that difficult, so I have never really understood why people want to avoid it.

Comment: I am not avoiding Burnside's theorem, it's just the question is present in Sylow Subgroup section without any mention of Burnside till that point so I am thinking there must be a solution

Comment: I am not convinced. There are other double starred questions in Herstein's book with the same feature that they do not appear to be solvable using the techniques developed so far. For example there is a question asking you to prove that the cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible over ${\mathbb Z}$, which is seriously difficult if you have never seen the proof before. But of course it would be interesting if someone could find a solution that did not amount to proving BTT or SZ.

Comment: Which book of I.N. Herstein are you using ?

Comment: Topics in Algebra, 2nd edition

Comment: The 1902 paper of Schur, entitled *Neuer Beweis eines satzes über endliche Gruppen*, contains this statement in III. Suzuki in his book claims that his proof is more or less the same as Zassenhaus's proof of the SZ theorem. Unfortunately I don't have access to this paper of Schur, so I cannot check. Kirtland's book uses crossed homomorphisms.

Answer (score 0):

This is exercise 3B.5 in Isaacs' *[Finite Group Theory](https://books.google.nl/books?id=E9kOCgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=finite%20group%20theory&hl=nl&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=finite%20group%20theory&f=false)* and it also appears as exercise 557* in John Rose's *[A Course on Group Theory](https://books.google.nl/books/about/A_Course_on_Group_Theory.html?id=-NuQQgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)*, where it is attributed to Isaai Schur (1902). In the latter exercise it is generalised to $P$ being a Hall-subgroup. I am not sure this can be proved by elementary means without an appeal to so-called *crossed homomorphisms* or even the *transfer* *map*. One of the easier consequences of these concepts and theory is the following, being a special case of the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem.

**Proposition** Let $A \unlhd G$ be abelian subgroup and assume gcd$(|A|,G:A|)=1$. Then $A$ has a complement.

So, if $P \in Syl_p(G)$ with $P \subseteq Z(G)$. Then there is a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $G=HP$ and $H \cap P=1$. Since $P$ is central it follows that $H$ is normal. Hence $G$ is isomorphic to the internal direct product $H \times P$.

Comment: I am doubtful about whether this answers the question, which I interpret as being "How could a reader of `Topics in Algebra' by I.N. Herstein be expected to answer this exercise?".

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware of this. I do not have the book of Herstein in my possession so not a clue what has been developed before this exercise.Isaacs and Rose at least needed the "machinery" as I have written. Also, the paper of Schur uses this. I also had the same idea as David Craven but in the end the argument does not work. As you remarked, the concept of a cross homomorphism or even transfer map is not that difficult.

Comment: For context, the idea of mine was to try to show that the set of all elements of order prime to $p$ is closed under multiplication (which it is) directly. I thought I had done this, but there is an error in the proof at a crucial stage. If $x$ and $y$ are elements and $xy$ has order a power of $p$ then it is easy to see that $xy=1$. If $xy$ has order a product of a power of $p$ with a $p'$-number then I thought I could do it but made a mistake. I quickly took down the proof, within a few minutes, but apparently was not fast enough!

Comment: David, I had the same idea and ended up with lcm$((o(x),o(y))=o(x) \cdot o(y)$ if $x$ and $y$ commute. Of course you need $\langle x \rangle \cap \langle y \rangle =1$ here. And that was not the case ...